# Problem with significant figures

Tags: data-analysis

I know that if I am multiplying/dividing my answer is the least number of significant figure in the data and if I am adding/subtracting my answer is the least number of decimal places i the data but what if I have a constant for example:

If I want to find the average of the data so I'm going to add them then divide by the number of data:

$$\frac{3.05 \cdot 2.05 \cdot 1.05}{3}= 2\text{ or }2.19$$

will the answer be one significant figure because of the three even if the three is not part of the data or will the answer be 3 significant figures as this is the least number if significant figures in the data being calculated.

Comment: You do know the number $3$ here is not $3.00000001$ or $2.99999999$ but exactly $3$, right? So the accuracy of $3$ is not "one significant digit" but infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $3$ in this case is **known** to be **exactly** $3$, you can treat it as if it had as many significant digits after it as the rest of your data (or better).

Hence you can write it as:

$$\frac{3.05 \cdot 2.05 \cdot 1.05}{3.00} = 2.19$$